# Mock private static final variable

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while using Mockito for writing Junit test case, could someonie tell me how to mock  below code snippet:

```
 clazz SomeCntroller {
    

    /** The Constant DATE_TIME_FORMATTER. */
    private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
*#  
 line 4 #   **private static final  FTPConfigPropery sampleProperty= SampleService.getInstance().getFTPConfigPropery(true);***



public void someMethod(){

-------------------------------


}
}
```

getting error at line 4, surprisingly date variable is also final and static but i am not getting any error there.

- Using @Mock/@InjectMocks for both FTPConfigProperty and SampleService class;
- Making this class variable a local variable (this works but unfortunately i cant d that because it someone else's code)

Comment: Please clean up this question and clarify. It's not really clear what you are doing, and what the error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.